# php setcookie is not working with no errors

Tags: php, cookies, cors, setcookie

I'm trying to set cookies with PHP. I wrote a login script that checks data received from the user with database data and then if data matched, it sets a cookie that stores username and password to be used in the next two hours.
This is a PHP script to handle an HTTP POST request and output JSON to be used in a react app.

I used ob in my code and I am sure that there are no headers sent before setting cookies.

This is how my code looks like.

```php
    <?php
        ob_start();

        function cook($user, $pass, $time){
            setcookie("user", $user, time() + $time, "/", "localhost", 0);
            setcookie("pass", $pass, time() + $time, "/", "localhost", 0);
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        //login code(receive data, check password, ...)

        cook($user, hash("sha512", $pass), 7200);

        $output = //my code output object

        echo json_encode($output);

        ob_end_flush();
```

There is no errors and exception.

**UPDATE:** I am using cross-origin request. My client is on localhost:3000 and PHP scripts are running on localhost:8080

Comment: The docs clearly state “no output will be sent (other than headers)” so this is not entirely true. Put your call to `cook` before the header.

Comment: Why are you storing a password/hash in a cookie?

Comment: Unless the browser is on the same machine as the web server localhost will not work. That needs to be the domain you are accessing the web server with. Or you can just not specify it.

Comment: Also It's not a good practice to store passwords in cookies even if they are hashed.

Comment: @Cue that's not working

Comment: @JasonK is there any way to fix this problem on my localhost?

Comment: So what should I do for setting a auto-login without using cookies?

Comment: Also added a redirect from localdev.com to localhost using /etc/hosts. It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. The actual problem was from the post request. It did not send the credentials with the request.
First, I sat withCredentials to true. Then changed some headers to accept credentials in my apache config like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localdev.localdev.com:3000"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Note: I also added a domain for my 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts as I mentioned in comments.
I know that is not exactly a PHP problem. But this may help.